# How to get an MD5 checksum, of a file in a web site. PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, web, hash, md5

I need to create a script in powershell. That validates the hash of a file located in a web site and if there are any changes in the file start downloading the file.

There is a way to validate the hash of the file without previously downloading the file to the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the content of a file to create a hash for it, so you always have to download the file first. This is easy in PowerShell, download the file and create the MD5 hash (checksum).

If you own the web site, create the MD5 hash on the server and just download that hash and compared it to a locally stored hash, if different, download the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this without downloading the file. An md5 checksum is generated from the file's contents, so in order to generate it with powershell you need the contents. Ergo you need to download the file.

I would advise generating the checksum directly on the web server via php or whatever language you use there. You could maybe save the checksums in a separate metadata file or append it to the original file's name. Then you can compare the checksum without downloading the full file.